# ¿Existe alguna forma de seleccionar un resultado especifico en una función "For" o variantes de esta?

Tags: java

Código:

```
 for (int divisores = 2; divisores < numero; divisores ++){ 

        if(numero % divisores == 0){ 
      System.out.println("Los divisores del numero evaluado son: " + divisores); 

  }
```

Me gustaría mostrar que números (divisores) multiplicados dan el numero ingresado 
ej:

```
18 = 2, 3, 6, 9 

2*9 = 18, 3*6 = 18
```

espero se entienda el código, no se utilizar las funciones de esta pagina

Comment: Edité la zona de etiquetas usadas en tu pregunta, pues javascript no es lo mismo que java; que de hecho es el lenguaje que estás usando en tu código.

Answer (score 5):

¿Que tal? el código que pusiste esta bien, solo le hice algunas modificaciones para que quede igual a como lo describís:

```
    System.out.println("Los divisores del numero evaluado son: ");
    System.out.print(numero + " = ");
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= numero/2; divisor ++) { 

        if(numero % divisor == 0)
        System.out.print(divisor + ", "); 

  }
```

Para mostrar por que divisores está compuesto el número a evaluar se me ocurrió lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println();
for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= numero/2 && divisor<=numero/divisor; divisor ++) { 

        if(numero % divisor == 0)
        System.out.println(divisor + "*" + (numero/divisor) + " = " + numero);
}
```

Espero que te haya sido útil

Comment: muy bueno! Lo testié con este sitio: https://www.numere-prime.ro/common-divisors-of-integers-numbers-calculator-finder.php que calcula todos los factores de un número dado y no falta ninguno

Comment: Se agradece tu respuesta Juan... me alegro que te haya servido

Comment: En realidad yo solo entré para  responder la pregunta pero no pude, y cuando vi tu respuesta la probé con cierta desconfianza jej pero verifiqué que estaba muy bien. Un saludo!

Comment: En ese caso gracias por dar tu feedback. Saludos!!